# Secure an API route without credentials

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js, server-side-rendering, next-auth

I have a form that checks if an email is already in my DB (/api/user?email=user@example.com), if it does, it responds with their information.

I can't seem to find a way to protect my API routes from someone going to postman and just brute forcing **GET** *https://example.com/api/user?email=name@domain.com* and collecting personal information.

I need this functionality without any login credentials. I know there must be an industry standard way of doing this. There are insurance providers that do this with their forms. (e.g. once you enter your email, is greets you with your name and asks you to finish filling out a form.)

In other words - I need my api route to somehow differentiate between a legit browser making those requests or someone with different intentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard, but you can protect your route from brute force:

1. Add rate limiting to avoid brute force from small range of IP's
2. Add captcha check to avoid non client side requests and cheap bots.
3. Generate session (or hashed url) for each user and allow only user's with session to complete form by entering email
4. Use csrf token to avoid non client request

Answer (score 0):

Without credentials there is no 100% bulletproof way of verifying an authentic request from a user versus one from someone or somewhere else. The "industry standard" is a certain level of personal data that can be exposed without any verification, as your example with insurance providers mentioned.

There are some ways to mitigate this, such as by checking the request headers; specifically origin, referrer, user-agent, etc. but all of these could still be bypassed if one really needed to. If I were in your place, and "absolutely had to have no credentials to validate the request", I would just return only a shallow amount of information such as an email and first name, which is essentially the same amount as anything else.